# Java recursively delete objects and move other objects into their place

Tags: java, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

I have an unknown depth recursive object and I need to delete specific nodes and bring their children into their place... That might not make sense so here is my best attempt at a representation:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "DELETE_THIS",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "MOVE THIS UP ONE NODE",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "id": "",
                    "children": [
                      {}
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "DELETE_THIS",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "MOVE THIS UP ONE NODE",
                "children": [
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "children": [
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm really struggling to understand what data structure or how I should handle this. At the moment everything is just a huge `List<Child>` and I don't know if I should be trying to make this into some kind of `Node` or `Tree`.

I attempted to use a `Stack<Child>` to pop things off and keep track of where I was but that ended up very messy and still didn't work.

Is someone able to help me out here with at least what data structure or method I should Google?

Kind regards

Comment: That is a tree.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a `Node` class that represents each node in the tree structure. It could be something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node {

    private String id = "";
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Node(String id, Node... children) {
        this.children.addAll(List.of(children));
    }

    public void setID(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void moveUpGrandChildren() {
        List<Node> grandChildren = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Node child : children) {
            grandChildren.addAll(child.getChildren());
        }
        children.clear();
        children.addAll(grandChildren);
    }

    // Assumes child node is in this node
    public void moveUpGrandChildren(Node child) {
        List<Node> grandChildren = child.getChildren();
        children.remove(child);
        children.addAll(grandChildren);
    }
}
```

Then you could use `moveUpGrandChildren()` to move the children into the parent node:

```
Node grandchild1 = new Node("grandchild1");
Node grandchild2 = new Node("grandchild2");
Node grandchild3 = new Node("grandchild3");
Node grandchild4 = new Node("grandchild4");
Node child1 = new Node("child1", grandchild1, grandchild2);
Node child2 = new Node("child2", grandchild3, grandchild4);
Node root = new Node("root", child1, child2);
root.moveUpGrandChildren(child1); // moves up first child's children
root.moveUpGrandChildren(); // moves up all children's children
```